# Using multiple HAVING clause on SQL statement using JSON_EXTRACT

Tags: mysql, sql, json, where-clause, having-clause

I am using MYSQL 6.x with JSON functions and have the following query that I am trying to use WHERE or HAVING to limit the recordset - there is a column called `properties` which is JSON column and I need to perform a search with multiple conditions on this json data

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(properties,'$.identifier') AS identifier,
       JSON_EXTRACT(properties,'$.workflow_type') AS workflow_type
       FROM workflow_pages HAVING workflow_type;
```

This returns the following data :-

```
+------------+---------------+
| identifier | workflow_type |
+------------+---------------+
| 9          | "dictionary"  |
| 13         | "dictionary"  |
| 11         | "dictionary"  |
| 13         | "rule"        |
| 134        | "rule"        |
+------------+---------------+
```

How do I perform the same query above to only return the rows which have the following conditions
`identifier IN 13, 134` AND `workflow_type = 'rule'`

How do I amend my query to do this as it seems MySQL doesn't allow for multiple HAVING conditions

Comment: Unrelated, but: there is no such thing as *MYSQL 6.x* (they jumped from 5.7 to 8.0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sure can have multiple conditions in the `HAVING` clause (as opposed to multiple `HAVING` clauses):

```
SELECT 
    JSON_EXTRACT(properties,'$.identifier') AS identifier,
    JSON_EXTRACT(properties,'$.workflow_type') AS workflow_type
FROM workflow_pages 
HAVING workflow_type = 'rule' AND identifier IN (13, 134)
```

But I would not actually recommend phrasing the query this way; you are relying on MySQL's extension to the SQL standard which allows aliases in the `HAVING` clause (and without a `GROUP BY`), and it makes the query quite unclear in some regard. I find that it is much better to use a regular `WHERE` clause and repeat the expressions:

```
SELECT 
    JSON_EXTRACT(properties,'$.identifier') AS identifier,
    JSON_EXTRACT(properties,'$.workflow_type') AS workflow_type
FROM workflow_pages 
WHERE 
    JSON_EXTRACT(properties,'$.identifier') IN (12, 134)
    JSON_EXTRACT(properties,'$.workflow_type') = 'rule'
```

Or if you have a lot of conditions and don't want to do all the typing, you can use a subquery (I would expect MySQL to do predicate pushdown and optimize it for you under the hood):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        JSON_EXTRACT(properties,'$.identifier') AS identifier,
        JSON_EXTRACT(properties,'$.workflow_type') AS workflow_type
    FROM workflow_pages 
) t
WHERE workflow_type = 'rule' AND identifier IN (13, 134)
```